# Convert character into logical

Tags: r

In a survey, I put a question where people can leave any comments.
If a participant left any text in the response, I'd recode it as TRUE, but if they did not put anything, I'd recode it as FALSE. (So I am trying to convert a character type variable into a logical type.)

I tried to use:

```
dataset$variable <- dataset$variable %>% 
  plyr::revalue(c("NA"= FALSE, else = TRUE))
```

But else = TRUE is not working as I wanted. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Note that RStudio is just an IDE. The language you are using is R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% 
  mutate(variable = if_else(is.na(variable),FALSE,TRUE))
```

Comment: or simply: dataset %>% 
  mutate(variable = is.na(variable)==F)

Answer (score 1):

```r
data$columnName= ifelse(data$columnName== "Something", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical operators to get `TRUE`/`FALSE` values.

```
dataset <- data.frame(variable = c('NA', 'A', 'B', 'NA'))
dataset$result <- dataset$variable != "NA"
dataset

#  variable result
#1       NA  FALSE
#2        A   TRUE
#3        B   TRUE
#4       NA  FALSE
```

If you have real `NA` values you can use `is.na` -

```
dataset <- data.frame(variable = c(NA, 'A', 'B', NA))
dataset$result <- !is.na(dataset$variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
%>% ifelse(. == "NA", FALSE, TRUE)
```